# Want to change default delimiter to other symbol in bootstrap tokenfield

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, autosuggest, bootstrap-tokenfield

I'm using bootstrap tokenizers for autosuggest- [refer link](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/)

I want to make few custom changes to it, has anyone tried doing these things.
This plugin seems to work great. 
But I have few queries, It would be great if anyone help me, overcoming those.

**Change default delimiter**

I want to change default delimiter comma to other symbol like "|" or "/"
As I have suggestions that has comma in it. And this makes it breaking a single term into multiple boxes.

**For Ex.** I have a term named "Hotel RajMahal, Pune"
It should treat this as a single term in search box, but it shows 2 different terms.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the default delimiter by passing - delimiter: '|' or an array ['|', ',']

Example -

```
$('#ajey').tokenfield(
    {   
        createTokensOnBlur: true,
        delimiter: ['|', ','],
        typeahead: [
            {
                minLength: 1,
                highlight:true
            }, 
            {   
                source: engine.ttAdapter(),
                templates: {
                }
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

Enjoy - [Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Ajey/mm401sfL/1/)